# Sankalpam for Switzerland location

Tags: sandhyavandanam

Please convert the below sankalpam that i recite during my sandhyavandanam into location specific one. I am right now in Zurich,Switzerland. Can someone give me sankalpam specific to Zurich?

Shubhe shobhana muhurthe, aadya bramhana, dwitiya pararthe, swetha varaha kalpe, vaivasvatha manvanthare, kaliyuge, prathama paade,JAMBU DWEEPE, BHARATA VARSHE, BHARATA KHANDE, DANDAKAARANYE, GODAVARYAAHA, DAKSHINE TEERE, SHAALIVAAHANA SHAKHE, BOUDHAVATHARE, RAMA KSHETHRE, KRISHNA KAAVERIYO MADHYA PRADESHE, samastha devatha brahmana harihara sannidhou......

I am sure, everything in the capital letter will change. Can anyone kindly, sincerely reply to this question...?

Comment: What temples located near Zurich recite, that will be same to you too. If there are some temples in switzerlan, ask the priest there. Shaka and avatara doesn't change. They indicate time.